# ipython notebook and patsy categorical variable (formula)

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels, patsy

I had the same error as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545242/statsmodels-categorical-data-from-formula-using-pandas).

What is weird, is that it works (with the answer provided) in an ipython shell, but not in an ipython notebook. But it's related to the `C()` operator, because without it works (but not as an operator)

Same with that [example](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html) :

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np
import pandas


url = "http://vincentarelbundock.github.com/Rdatasets/csv/HistData/Guerry.csv"
df = pandas.read_csv(url)
df = df[['Lottery', 'Literacy', 'Wealth', 'Region']].dropna()
df.head()
mod = smf.ols(formula='Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + Region', data=df)
res = mod.fit()
print res.summary()
```

This works well, both in the ipython notebook and in the shell, and `patsy` treats `Region` as categorical variable because it's composed of strings.

but if I try this (as in the tutorial) :

```
res = smf.ols(formula='Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + C(Region)', data=df).fit()
```

I got an error in the ipython notebook:

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Note that both in the notebook and in the shell `statsmodels` and `patsy` are the same versions (0.5.0 and 0.3.0 respectively)

Do you have the same error ?

Comment: I don't get any error, neither with patsy 0.2.1 nor with patsy 0.3. I'm using statsmodels development version, but I don't think there are any statsmodels related changes. The pandas versions I used are 0.12 and 0.14.1dev.

Comment: @user333700 : You don't get the error in the ipython notebook ? Do you have any idea on how to fix this from my side if it's not a bug ?

Comment: No error in the notebook. (In the notebook I only have pandas 0.12, but both patsy versions.) I don't have much idea about how to fix it since I have no suspect about what might be wrong. Try to look at the details of the traceback and check where there might be a `C` series defined. Do you have many automatic imports that might interfere?

Comment: @user333700 : So actually it was because I had a variable in my namespace called `C`, but not in the DataFrame. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the problem.

It is because there was a variable called `C` that I used way earlier in the notebook. What is surprising though, is that it was not a column of the `df` I used.

Anyway, the basic solution is :

```
del C
```

before running the regression.

Hope this will help people facing the same problem.

But I'm still not sure whether this is an expected behavior of patsy.

Comment: This is expected behavior. The evaluation environment of patsy resolves to the caller's namespace. We hard-code this in statsmodels. See the `eval_env` variable in the [patsy documentation](http://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API-reference.html). I am debating exposing this to users so it's easier to avoid situations like this.

Comment: @jseabold : Thanks for your comment. I think it would be great to just mention this in the tutorial (like [this one, section Categorical Variable](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html)), with some kind of warning box. Because I think this doc is a bit too technical for such "small" problem. If I had seen it, not sure it would have helped me.

Comment: I added a note about it and the ability for users to control which namespace environment the formula is evaluated in. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/2031